# Protocol Error When Using Vite.js + Cloudflare

Tags: laravel, ssl, protocols, vite, cloudflare

I am using Cloudflare in my Laravel project and it gives a protocol error in the Vite.js console. The data I have is as follows:
When I set the server setting as below, I see that my js and css files are trying to be published via my IP address. But since there is a protocol error, access to the files is not possible.

```
export default {
  server: {
    port: 5173,
    host: 123.456.789,
  },
};
```

When I type the domain address directly instead of the IP address, as a result of the `npm run dev` command, it says that Vite cannot resolve the IP address because the Name Servers are on Cloudflare.

Even if I enable the IP Address to be accessed via https, as you know, IP addresses cannot receive SSL and this again prevents the browser from accessing the files.

To summarize, what I want to do is this; I want to be able to use Vite.js without any problems when using Cloudflare Nameservers. In fact, I want the path of my assets to appear directly as my domain address, not an IP address. But as I said, if I write my domain address as the host in the vite.js configs, unfortunately it sees the IP address as an IP belonging to cloudflare and cannot resolve it.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

After building the project "npm run build" and upload it to the server, delete the "hot" file from the public folder. You do not need to add any server config in the vite config.  It worked for me.